# How to create keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 12.04 for reboot/shutdown that can be executed by even non-root users

Tags: shortcuts, reboot

I wish to create a shortcut key for reboot/shutdownfor all the users (including non-root users). 
I have tried creating a custom shortcut key Ctrl+R and assigned it to the command “**gksu reboot**” however Ubuntu requires root privileges to execute the command and throws up the message

***Failed to run reboot as root**
The underlying authorization mechanism (sudo) does not allow you to run this program. Contact the system administrator.*

I do not wish to give root privileges to the users and essentially want to execute the Shutdown/Reboot (that is usually accessed through the gear icon by all the users) through commands using shortcut keys

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow all users to run only the `reboot` command with no password, `gksu` should pick up this permission correctly.  Add this to your `sudoers` file:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

PLEASE don't edit `sudoers` directly. Use `sudo visudo` to get an editor, which will syntax-check the file once you save it. Append that line at the end, then save and exit it. If `visudo` finds a problem it will help you so you don't lock yourself out of your system.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help and also for the suggestion to use visudo. Interestingly the GUI option somehow does not need editing sudoers file.